# How do I Parse JSON-like Data from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: json, yahoo-finance, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am trying to use HTML and JavaScript to get some stock quotes from Yahoo and display them in a gadget for myself. I am querying the following URL, with an example symbol:
    https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=aaba

The output is JSON or JSON-like, depending on where single- and double-quotes matter. TOR Browser recognizes the data as JSON-formatted.

My code can pull the data and receive it, but `JSON.parse` does not work on the output. Here's an example of the code I'm writing and loading with IE11 to test it before going to the gadget.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="symbol"></p>
    <p id="shortName"></p>
    <p id="bid"></p>
    <p id="debug"></p>
    <script>
      var objJSON;
      var objXHR=new XMLHttpRequest();
      objXHR.open("GET", "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=aaba");
      objXHR.onreadystatechange=function() {
        console.log(objXHR.status);
        if (objXHR.readyState == 4 && objXHR.status == 200) {
          console.log("Ready==4");
          console.log(objXHR.responseText); //log the response
          objJSON = JSON.parse(objXHR.responseText);
          //objJSON = JSON.parse('{ "symbol":"aaba", "shortName":"Altaba", "bid":0}'); // Test data in properly-formatted JSON text
          console.log("length " + Object.keys(objJSON).length); //indicator whether it parsed
          document.getElementById("symbol").innerHTML = "symbol " + objJSON.symbol;
          document.getElementById("shortName").innerHTML = "shortName " + objJSON.shortName;
          document.getElementById("bid").innerHTML = "bid " + objJSON.bid;
        }
      };
      objXHR.send(null);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The data doesn't *have* to be from Yahoo, but it does have to be something that I can get into a Windows Gadget and work, and be as simple as possible, because I'm not that advanced.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` is not available in windows gadgets JavaScript. But you may use some polyfill implementation. This [code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) does the job for me. Just copy and paste it in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just didn't understand the JSON object/array structure well enough. It looks like the string returned by Yahoo Finance is {object:{array[object:value]}}. I used console.log to march through the JSON structure in IE11, and eventually got there.